# Could you remove (or change) the "Add comment" hint from deleted answers?

Tags: bug, comments, deleted-posts

### Steps to reproduce:

Hover the ***comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews*** text on [any deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18452240/960757) or locked post and you'll see the following hint (this hint is normally used for ***add comment*** link at active posts):

[image]

### Question:

Could you remove the extra hint from deleted posts ?

Comment: No free hand circles?

Comment: Why remove it? Comment usage instructions are welcome anywhere...